# Arduino - Error borrando memoria EEPROM en MEGA

Tags: c++, c, arduino

soy nuevo en Arduino y estoy teniendo un inconveniente con Arduino...tengo 2 placas. Una es un Arduino UNO y otra es un Arduino Mega. Corro el siguiente programita en ambas, que lo unico que hace es limpiar la memoria EEPROM y mostrar como quedó. La idea es que siempre la salida deberia ser 0 porque la memoria se esta borrando. Pongo el codigo y las distintas salidas.

```
#include <EEPROM.h>

void EEPROMWriteInt(int address, int value); //2 Bytes, LE DIGO COMO GUARDAR
int EEPROMReadInt(int address);  

int32_t numberSens = 0; 
int32_t numberDESP = 0; 
int32_t numberGI = 0;
int32_t numberGD = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for (int nL = 0; nL < EEPROM.length(); nL++) { 
    EEPROM.write(nL, 0);
  }

  numberSens = EEPROMReadInt(1);
  numberDESP = EEPROMReadInt(3);
  numberGI = EEPROMReadInt(5);
  numberGD = EEPROMReadInt(7);

  Serial.print("numberSens ");
  Serial.println(numberSens);
  Serial.print("numberDESP ");
  Serial.println(numberDESP);
  Serial.print("numberGI ");
  Serial.println(numberGI);
  Serial.print("numberGD ");
  Serial.println(numberGD);
}

void loop() {

}

void EEPROMWriteInt(int address, int value) {
  byte hiByte = highByte(value);
  byte loByte = lowByte(value);

  EEPROM.write(address, hiByte);
  EEPROM.write(address + 1, loByte);   
}

int EEPROMReadInt(int address)
{
  byte hiByte = EEPROM.read(address);
  byte loByte = EEPROM.read(address + 1);

  return word(hiByte, loByte); 
}
```

Entonces, la salida en Arduino UNO es:

```
numberSens 0
numberDESP 0
numberGI 0
numberGD 0
```

La salida en Arduino MEGA es:

```
numberSens 4353
numberDESP 1408
numberGI 0
numberGD 256
```

Alguien tiene idea o una pista porque puede estar pasando esto? Se los agradezco de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu ejemplo funcionó bien en el uno y mal en el mega. PERO encontré el/los problemas. El primer problema es que el MEGA tiene los bytes de delante (0 al 6 aprox. dañados). Esto me di cuenta dado que el mismo ejemplo lo hago grabar en posiciones de memoria mas alta y funciona correctamente. 
El segundo problema era que int32_t ocupa 4 bytes y en mi ejemplo lo estoy tratando de escribir en 2 bytes, con lo cual, el primer numero lo guarda bien, pero a partir del segundo empieza a solaparse. Para resolverlo utilicé una metodo de lectura y uno de escritura que utilizan la cantidad de bytes de acuerdo al tipo de datos. Les dejo el codigo por si a alguien le sirve. Gracias a todos.

```
template <class T> int EEPROM_write(int ee, const T& value);
template <class T> int EEPROM_read(int ee, T& value);

template <class T> int EEPROM_write(int ee, const T& value)
{
    const byte* p = (const byte*)(const void*)&value;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(value); i++)
          EEPROM.write(ee++, *p++);
    return i;
}

template <class T> int EEPROM_read(int ee, T& value)
{
    byte* p = (byte*)(void*)&value;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(value); i++)
          *p++ = EEPROM.read(ee++);
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El metodo write() trabaja con bytes,si vas a usar tipos de variables diferentes ,como por ejemplo int o incluso estructuras de datos,usa los metodos put() y get():

```
#include <EEPROM.h>
const int NEXT_POS = sizeof(int) + 1; // siguiente posicion a escribir de la eeprom para valores int
const int MAX_REGISTERS = EEPROM.length()/sizeof(int); // Maximo de registros segun el tipo de variable,en este caso int
const int FIRST_POS = 0; // Primer registro eeprom
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int position = 0;
  for(int cont = 0;cont < MAX_REGISTERS;cont++){ // Pone un 0 en todos los registros
    EEPROM.put(position,0);
    position += NEXT_POS; 
    delay(10);
  }
  position = 0;
  int value;
   for(int cont = 0;cont < MAX_REGISTERS;cont++){ // Lectura
    EEPROM.get(position,value);
    position += NEXT_POS; 
    Serial.println(value);
    delay(10);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

No lo he probado en el mega ,deberia funcionar.